# Erro ao tentar buscar a localização

Tags: android, geolocalização, android-permission

Tenho um projeto que ao acessar a activity, ele já busca o local e preenche os dados, para salvá-los, posteriormente. Mas quando é o primeiro acesso, quando se busca as permissões, ele sempre entende que não foi dada a permissão para o GPS.

Segue imagem:
[image: Imagem]

Segue código:

```
private void startLocationUpdates(){
    //Inicia GPS para buscar o local atual
    if (!edtLatitude.getText().toString().isEmpty() || !edtLongitude.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        return;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        showAlertOk("Permissão para acessar GPS não foi concedida, portanto não será possível buscar o endereço atual automaticamente.");
    }else {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        showProgress(true);
    }
}
```

Portanto, gostaria de entender onde estou errando, pois sempre que é o primeiro acesso, cai neste alerta e não chama o local. Quando a permissão já está dada, funciona. Normalmente.

EDIT:
Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="projeto.projeto1_teste">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Allows the API to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Allows the API to use the Global Positioning System (GPS) to determine the device's location to within a very small area. -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="APIGOOGLE"/>

        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT2:

Permissões em tempo de execução para android 6.0

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Solicita as permissões
    String[] permissoes = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
    };
    Permissions.validate(this, 0, permissoes);
```

Classe Permissions:

```
public class Permissions {

        /**
         * Solicita as permissões
         */
        public static boolean validate(Activity activity, int requestCode, String... permissions) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                // Valida permissão
                boolean ok = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (!ok) {
                    list.add(permission);
                }
            }
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                // Tudo ok, retorna true
                return true;
            }

            // Lista de permissões que falta acesso.
            String[] newPermissions = new String[list.size()];
            list.toArray(newPermissions);

            // Solicita permissão
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, newPermissions, 1);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54632/discussion-on-question-by-henrique-mendes-erro-ao-tentar-buscar-a-localizacao)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta chamar novamente a função de começar a buscar a localização depois de pedir a permissão:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {

                // Não concedeu, informar ou tratar 


            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa, valeu. Minha implementação foi basicamente esta, mas com a lógica invertida. Muito Obrigado! Funcionou blz.